# Powershell - create directories form files in a dierectory

Tags: windows, powershell, file, directory

I am trying to clean up and group files in a directory by creating subdirectories and then copying the files into the new directories.

Example:

```
test01.a.jpg
test01.a.txt 
test01.b.bak 
test01.b.txt 
test02.a.txt
test02.a.jpg
test02.a.bak
test03.a.txt
test03.a.bak
test03.b.txt
```

I wish to create subdirectories like `test01`, `test02`, `test03` and ideally copy the relevant files over. All groups will have a txt file but more or less of the others.

To create the directories I have got as far as

```
gci -file *.txt | New-Item -ItemType directory $_.name
```

which doesn't work as expected.

Comment: [1] show the result you are getting from the posted sample file names. ///// [2] take a look at using `$_.BaseName.Split('.')[0]` to get the "before the embedded dot" part of the base name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your files have names like that, you can simply split the filename on the dot and take only the first part as new folder name.

Then test if a subfolder like that already exists (if not create it) and move the file.
Something like this

```
$sourcePath = 'D:\Test'  # put the real path to the files here

# if you want only the files with extension .txt, use filter '*.*.txt'
(Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -File -Filter '*.*.*') | ForEach-Object {
    # use the first part of the file name for subdirectory name
    $destinationPath = Join-Path -Path $sourcePath -ChildPath $_.Name.Split(".")[0]
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationPath -PathType Container)) {
        # if a subdirectory with that name does not already exist, create it
        $null = New-Item -Path $destinationPath -ItemType Directory
    }
    # now move the file to that (new) destination folder
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $destinationPath
}
```

Comment: Awesome! does exactly what i need. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You can remove the `if` statement and just write `$null = New-Item -Path $destinationPath -ItemType Directory -Force`. This way it won't cause an error when the path already exists.

Comment: @zett42 you're right. It is just an old habit to test first.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, algorithm is simple (we don't need to previously compare names of files. All we need is just use a $_.BaseName property)

```
<#Creating folders and moving files using BaseName property #>
gci *.txt | % { new-item -ItemType Directory -Path ($_.Directory.ToString() + "\" + $_.BaseName.ToString())}    
gci -file | % { Move-item $_.Fullname ($_.Directory.ToString() + "\" + $_.BaseName.ToString())}
```